# Removing '=' in bulk from formulae with parse error in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet with a column of phone numbers with the format **=6011-1111 2222**. The '=' symbols in front is making Google Sheet to treat them as formulae. Since the formula is invalid, the results of all cells are **#ERROR!**.

How can I remove all the '=' symbols in a quick way? I've tried **=REGEXREPLACE("=6011-1111 2222", "=", "")** and SUBSTITUTE but they won't work as long as the cells are showing "#ERROR!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FORMULATEXT()` function. Try-

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A2),"=","")
```

[image]

Better to use `Find & Replace` with option `Also search within formulas.`

[image]